# How do i use the database created using sqlite in my project?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am on a project where i have a database with 2 or more tables n lots of entries. So i am using sqlite to create this database. As i have read in few other answers i will have to copy the database file to the assets folder. now i have the database file in the assets folder. Here is the code i have used for DataBaseHelperClass

```
package com.example.basic;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelperClass";

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.astro/databases/";
    // Data Base Name.
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.sqlite";
    // Data Base Version.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Table Names of Data Base.
    static final String TABLE_Name = "Totlist";

    public Context context;
    static SQLiteDatabase sqliteDataBase;

    public DataBaseHelperClass(Context context) {       
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null ,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        //check if the database exists
        boolean databaseExist = checkDataBase();

        if(databaseExist){
            // Do Nothing.
        }else{
            this.createDataBase();         
            copyDataBase(); 
        }// end if else dbExist
    } // end createDataBase().


    public boolean checkDataBase(){
        File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        return databaseFile.exists();        
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{ 
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME); 
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
        //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

      //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();




    }

    /**
     * This method opens the data base connection.
     * First it create the path up till data base of the device.
     * Then create connection with data base.
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{      
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        sqliteDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
    }

    /**
     * This Method is used to close the data base connection.
     */
    public synchronized void close() { 
        if(sqliteDataBase != null)
            sqliteDataBase.close(); 
        super.close(); 
    }

    public String getUserNameFromDB(){
        String query = "select desc From "+TABLE_Name;
        Cursor cursor = sqliteDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
        String description = null;
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
                    description = cursor.getString(0);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return description;
    }

    public String tot(){
        String rawQuery = "SELECT tot from Totlist WHERE Tid=1";
        Cursor cursor = sqliteDataBase.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
        String desc=null;
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    desc=cursor.getString(0);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

        return desc;
    }

    public String chq()
    {
        String q="hee";
        return q;
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // No need to write the create table query.
        // As we are using Pre built data base.
        // Which is ReadOnly.
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // No need to write the update table query.
        // As we are using Pre built data base.
        // Which is ReadOnly.
        // We should not update it as requirements of application.
    }   
}
```

this shows lots of errors in the logcat. one of them is "error opening trace file: no such file or directory (2)". The problem could be that the file in assets is not copied to the default location n hence it says no such file or directory. this is my second question about this database thing n still i am not able to get the result from it. The code in my mainactivity is like this.

```
package com.example.basic;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Basic extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic);


        DataBaseHelperClass db = new DataBaseHelperClass(this);
        String s=db.chq();
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        tv.setText(s);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.basic, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

i only have these two .java files in my project. anything wrong in this?

Comment: `error opening trace file: no such file or directory (2)` This is nothing to do with your code.  What do you mean `i am not able to get the result from it`?

Comment: then what is the error. y doesnt the query i want execute is not working?? the emulator says it has stopped. can u pls tel where i am wrong

Comment: 1) You really only need to post this comment once.  2) If you change your code and expect an answer, post the new code!  Very few of us are psychic.   3) "it shows that it has stopped working, what is the problem" contains no information. If you want help, learn how to describe the symptoms you are seeing.  It is likely that doing so will let you solve your own problem.

Comment: i dint change d code. i just put the code in mainactivity here. when i call getUserNameFromDB() or tot() the emulator says it has stopped. if i do not call any of these 2, it works fine. am not an expert in this, but i thought the problem could be either in those 2 methods or in the database connection. well, i edited the post just to make my question descriptive enough

Answer (score 1):

Using https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper will make it super easy to ship your prebuilt sqllite db.

You just need to copy the zipped sqllite file in your assets folder and it will be copied the first time you need to use the db.

Comment: i just did some modifications to my code n now the code is working. but when i try to call tot() or getUserNameFromDB() it shows that it has stopped working. what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

SqlLiteOpenHelper is intented to support creating and/or updating a database the first time it is opened.  It will create an empty database for you and expect you to create tables in it.

That is not what you are doing -- your database already exists.  It just needs to be copied to the correct location.

Thus you should not attempt to extend SqlLiteOpenHelper.  Just copy the database to the correct place if necessary and open it (you have the code to do that already written.)

A few suggestions:

Rather than hard-coding a path to the working directory as DB_PATH, you should call context.getFilesDir(); to find the path to your application's private directory. (just as you are correctly using context.getAssets() to find the assets directory).

Once you get the name of your local directory you can append the name of your databases directory and the name of the actual database file.

You should also add error checking to be sure you were successful in opening the files.

Comment: i just did some modifications to my code n now the code is working. but when i try to call tot() or getUserNameFromDB() it shows that it has stopped working. what is the problem